# How to resolve Pending Registration interruption in GigyaSwift v1.0

Tags: ios, swift, gigya

I am trying to handle a Pending Registration interruption in GigyaSwift V1.0. I am able to go inside the pending registration, but i'm not entirely sure what to do next. I am trying to show the screenset but the app crashes with a SIGABRT error.

Here is my code:

```
    gigya.login(with: .facebook, viewController: self, completion: { (result) in

    switch result {
    case .success(let data):
        print(data)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

        guard let interruption = error.interruption else {
            gigya.logout { (_) in
            }
            return }
        // Evaluate interruption.
        switch interruption {
        case .pendingRegistration(let resolver):
            gigya.showScreenSet(with: "Default-RegistrationLogin" ,
                                viewController: self,
                                params:[ "startScreen": "gigya-complete-registration-screen"],
                                completion: { (res) in


            })
            break
        default:
            break
        }

    }
    })
```

I think i need to put a regToken as a parameter but i am not able to access it through the resolver since it has an internal access modifier.

When i tried to do this in a new project, the SIGABRT error is more descriptive for some reason:

```
2019-07-25 17:19:11.273269+0800 GigyaTester[15773:243216] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5986fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ab3cac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b598555 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000109f97b3c _writeJSONValue + 706
    4   Foundation                          0x0000000109f9ba98 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke + 176
    5   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010bc2f481 $ss26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryC23enumerateKeysAndObjects7options5usingySi_ys9UnmanagedVyyXlG_AHSpys5UInt8VGtXBtFTf4dnn_n + 897
    6   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010ba4f8db $ss26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryC23enumerateKeysAndObjects7options5usingySi_ys9UnmanagedVyyXlG_AHSpys5UInt8VGtXBtFTo + 43
    7   Foundation                          0x0000000109f9b046 _writeJSONObject + 466
    8   Foundation                          0x0000000109f9ba98 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke + 176
    9   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010bc2f481 $ss26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryC23enumerateKeysAndObjects7options5usingySi_ys9UnmanagedVyyXlG_AHSpys5UInt8VGtXBtFTf4dnn_n + 897
    10  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010ba4f8db $ss26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryC23enumerateKeysAndObjects7options5usingySi_ys9UnmanagedVyyXlG_AHSpys5UInt8VGtXBtFTo + 43
    11  Foundation                          0x0000000109f9b046 _writeJSONObject + 466
    12  Foundation                          0x0000000109f9ba98 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke + 176
    13  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010bc2f481 $ss26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryC23enumerateKeysAndObjects7options5usingySi_ys9UnmanagedVyyXlG_AHSpys5UInt8VGtXBtFTf4dnn_n + 897
    14  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010ba4f8db $ss26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryC23enumerateKeysAndObjects7options5usingySi_ys9UnmanagedVyyXlG_AHSpys5UInt8VGtXBtFTo + 43
    15  Foundation                          0x0000000109f9b046 _writeJSONObject + 466
    16  Foundation                          0x0000000109f9ba98 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke + 176
    17  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010bc2f481 $ss26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryC23enumerateKeysAndObjects7options5usingySi_ys9UnmanagedVyyXlG_AHSpys5UInt8VGtXBtFTf4dnn_n + 897
    18  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010ba4f8db $ss26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryC23enumerateKeysAndObjects7options5usingySi_ys9UnmanagedVyyXlG_AHSpys5UInt8VGtXBtFTo + 43
    19  Foundation                          0x0000000109f9b046 _writeJSONObject + 466
    20  Foundation                          0x0000000109f9ba98 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke + 176
    21  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010bc2f481 $ss26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryC23enumerateKeysAndObjects7options5usingySi_ys9UnmanagedVyyXlG_AHSpys5UInt8VGtXBtFTf4dnn_n + 897
    22  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010ba4f8db $ss26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionaryC23enumerateKeysAndObjects7options5usingySi_ys9UnmanagedVyyXlG_AHSpys5UInt8VGtXBtFTo + 43
    23  Foundation                          0x0000000109f9b046 _writeJSONObject + 466
    24  Foundation                          0x0000000109f97826 -[_NSJSONWriter dataWithRootObject:options:error:] + 124
    25  Foundation                          0x0000000109f9a3b7 +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 337
    26  Gigya                               0x000000010a8165db $sSD5GigyaE6asJsonSSvgSS_ypTg5 + 459
    27  Gigya                               0x000000010a87ac4e $s5Gigya20PluginViewControllerC11sendRequest33_AECB03F2DE2968001A01CE9A6BBBD70ALL10callbackId9apiMethod6paramsySS_SSSDyS2SGtFyAA0A9ApiResultOySDySSAA10AnyCodableVGGcfU_ + 926
    28  Gigya                               0x000000010a87d49d $s5Gigya20PluginViewControllerC11sendRequest33_AECB03F2DE2968001A01CE9A6BBBD70ALL10callbackId9apiMethod6paramsySS_SSSDyS2SGtFyAA0A9ApiResultOySDySSAA10AnyCodableVGGcfU_TATm + 29
    29  Gigya                               0x000000010a87d3e0 $s5Gigya20PluginViewControllerC11sendRequest33_AECB03F2DE2968001A01CE9A6BBBD70ALL10callbackId9apiMethod6paramsySS_SSSDyS2SGtFyAA0A9ApiResultOySDySSAA10AnyCodableVGGcfU_TA + 16
    30  Gigya                               0x000000010a844bd6 $s5Gigya0A9ApiResultOySDySSAA10AnyCodableVGGIegg_AGIegn_TRTA + 38
    31  Gigya                               0x000000010a845959 $s5Gigya0A9ApiResultOySDySSAA10AnyCodableVGGIegg_AGIegn_TRTA.69 + 9
    32  Gigya                               0x000000010a83bd18 $s5Gigya10ApiServiceC14validateResult33_D119E9E6D70D9DCFB59B48B23E442E39LL12responseType4data10completionyxm_So6NSDataCSgyAA0abE0OyxGctSeRzSERzlF + 1944
    33  Gigya                               0x000000010a83b1cf $s5Gigya10ApiServiceC4send5model12responseType10completionyAA0B12RequestModelV_xmyAA0aB6ResultOyxGctSeRzSERzlFySo6NSDataCSg_s5Error_pSgtcfU_ + 1151
    34  Gigya                               0x000000010a83b579 $s5Gigya10ApiServiceC4send5model12responseType10completionyAA0B12RequestModelV_xmyAA0aB6ResultOyxGctSeRzSERzlFySo6NSDataCSg_s5Error_pSgtcfU_TA + 41
    35  Gigya                               0x000000010a8782e4 $s5Gigya14NetworkAdapterC4send5model10completionyAA15ApiRequestModelV_ySo6NSDataCSg_s5Error_pSgtctFySo10GSResponseCSg_AMtcfU_ + 324
    36  Gigya                               0x000000010a879251 $s5Gigya14NetworkAdapterC4send5model10completionyAA15ApiRequestModelV_ySo6NSDataCSg_s5Error_pSgtctFySo10GSResponseCSg_AMtcfU_TA + 17
    37  Gigya                               0x000000010a878170 $sSo10GSResponseCSgs5Error_pSgIeggg_ACSo7NSErrorCSgIeyByy_TR + 64
    38  GigyaInfra                          0x000000010aa270b1 -[GSRequest finishWithResponse:error:] + 293
    39  GigyaInfra                          0x000000010aa268dc __33-[GSRequest sendValidatedRequest]_block_invoke_3 + 504
    40  GigyaInfra                          0x000000010aa226e7 +[GSResponse responseForMethod:data:completionHandler:] + 614
    41  GigyaInfra                          0x000000010aa265eb __33-[GSRequest sendValidatedRequest]_block_invoke_2 + 610
    42  CFNetwork                           0x000000010cbd1178 __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
    43  CFNetwork                           0x000000010cbe7c56 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 172
    44  Foundation                          0x0000000109eb6412 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    45  Foundation                          0x0000000109eb631a -[NSBlockOperation main] + 68
    46  Foundation                          0x0000000109eb31f4 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 688
    47  Foundation                          0x0000000109eb8f5b __NSOQSchedule_f + 227
    48  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c5cf725 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
    49  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c5c1db5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    50  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c5cf080 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1540
    51  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b4ff8a9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    52  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b4f9f56 __CFRunLoopRun + 2310
    53  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b4f9302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    54  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010fd342fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    55  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116dfcba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    56  GigyaTester                         0x00000001080f208b main + 75
    57  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c636541 start + 1
    58  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I do not understand the implementation of pending registration in the GigyaDemoApp. Here is their code :

```
@IBAction func loginWithProviders(_ sender: Any) {
    gigya.socialLoginWith(providers: [.facebook, .google, .line], viewController: self, params: [:]) { [weak self] (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            print(data)
            self?.resultTextView?.text = data.toJson()
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)

            guard let interruption = error.interruption else { return }
            // Evaluage interruption.
            switch interruption {
            case .pendingRegistration(let resolver):
                resolver.setAccount(params: ["data": ["specialCode": "20"]])
            case .pendingVerification(let regToken):
                print("regToken: \(regToken)")
            case .conflitingAccount(let resolver):
                resolver.linkToSite(loginId: resolver.conflictingAccount?.loginID ?? "", password: "123123")
            default:
                break
            }

        }
    }

}
```

How am i supposed to handle the Pending Registration interruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like you forgot to close the square brackets.

**Try this:**

```
gigya.login(with: .facebook, viewController: self, completion: { (result) in

switch result {
case .success(let data):
    print(data)
case .failure(let error):
    print(error)

    guard let interruption = error.interruption else {
        gigya.logout { (_) in
        }
        return }
    // Evaluate interruption.
    switch interruption {
    case .pendingRegistration(let resolver):
        gigya.showScreenSet(with: "Default-RegistrationLogin" ,
                            viewController: self,
                            params:[ "startScreen": "gigya-complete-registration-screen"],
                            completion: { (res) in


        })
        break
    default:
        break
    }

}
})
```

Also you can't open `screenSet` in `pendingRegistration` interruption at this time, you need to open custom `ViewController` and use `resolver.setAccount` to update the required params.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The missing bracket was an editing mistake i made while creating this post, my bad. What do you mean by a custom viewcontroller? I would have to make my own form then? Does that mean i wont be able to use the screenset feature for pending registration?

Comment: When you open ׳screenset׳ to finish flow, like your code, you need to add ׳regToken׳ to the params, in 1.0.0 version the ׳regToken׳ not available. Gigya released new version today, after you upgrade you can get the ׳regToken׳ from the resolver and put it on the params.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for telling me about the update. I added the regToken as a parameter but opening the screenset is still returning a SIGABRT error. Should i be trying to open the screenset? Or making my own view?

Comment: Show screenset to resolve the interruption is not supported, you can make a custom view and use ׳resolver.setAccount׳ to resolver the ׳pendingRegistration׳,
Also it's look like you have an issue with the params,